# jQuery DataTable delete Tr with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My Table

```
<table id="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td><button onclick="doDeleteClick('row1')">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td><button onclick="doDeleteClick('row2')">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row3">
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td><button onclick="doDeleteClick('row3')">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in a function, I tried

```
$('#grid').DataTable().row($('#row-2')).remove().draw();
```

use a function to execute by sending the parameter, how to do this in a row?

Comment: Are you specifically talking about the [Data tables for Jquery Plugin](https://datatables.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

just create buttons like this

```
<button data-id="some-unique-id" class="removeBtn">Delete</button>
```

and then use simple jquery

```
$(".removeBtn").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    //Do something with the id
});
```